# Can't Get WP 8.1 AdControl to Engage on User Click

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, ads, monogame

I have a universal app project for Windows/WP 8.1, and I am attempting to get the Ads to work on both platforms. In the OnApplyTemplate function of my control, I have an #ifdef to dynamically create the AdControl for either Windows or WP. The code works great on Windows, and on WP the ad shows up just fine; but when I click on it, nothing is happening. I have tried replacing the code with a dynamic Button to make sure something else isn't intercepting the clicks, and the Button works just fine. Any ideas?

```
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var baseGrid = (Grid)GetTemplateChild("_BaseGrid");
        var bannerGrid = (Grid)GetTemplateChild("_BannerGrid");

#if WINDOWS_APP
        bannerGrid.Height = 450;

        // Create the ad
        var ad = new Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdControl()
        {
            ApplicationId = "0b7b7910-f56d-477c-b0e9-3def577b6359",
            AdUnitId = "10056707",
            Height = 90,
            Width = 728,
            Visibility = AdVisibility,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        baseGrid.Children.Add(ad);

#else
        // Set the margins appropriately for WP
        bannerGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 55, 0, 50);

        /* This works just fine!
        var button = new Button()
        {
            Content = "Try This!",
            Height = 50,
            Width = 320,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        button.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) =>
        {
            Nova.Utilities.Logger.Info("User tapped on button.");
        };
        baseGrid.Children.Add(button);*/

        // Create the ads
        var ad = new Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdControl("f854ae91-1c0e-469c-8387-6c90ef8fa6a2", "11388154", true)
        {
            Height = 50,
            Width = 320,
            Visibility = AdVisibility,
            IsEnabled = true,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        ad.IsEngagedChanged += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) =>
            {
                Nova.Utilities.Logger.Info("User tapped on Ad.");
            };
        baseGrid.Children.Add(ad);
#endif
    }
```

Comment: I know this may be a shot in the dark, but have you checked the IsSupended flag? Maybe it is getting suspended somewhere else

Comment: @Pseudonym, that link seems to be exactly my problem. But it is quite old. I would expect that to be fixed by now, no?

Comment: Following a few more links, some people think it is related to not setting the current Content to a Frame, but a page instead. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/game-graphics-freeze-after-live-windows-8-1-store-ad-is-displayed-using-prime31-plugin.297778/

Comment: Currently, my page actually inherits from SwapChainBackgroundPanel. It will be kind of a pain to change that stuff around.

Comment: I remove almost all of my other comments for clarity and put everything into my answer below

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like this may possibly still be a bug in the system:

> This is a bug in our system. We are still actively working on a fix
>   and work out a release plan. But here is a workaround I found. BTW,
>   this workaround hasn't been fully tested in our team.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/053fe091-8ffb-4d6f-a5ca-f39cff4af618/ads-not-responding-to-tap-or-click?forum=aiaforwinphone

Per the comments, some digging showed it might be related not setting the current Context to a Frame correctly:

> MonoGame people have run into this problem too with the new Microsoft
>   Advertising SDK for Windows 8.1. They had to make changes to make the
>   ads work again. Maybe the prime31 June plugin needs a similar update?
>   I am asking in the prime31 support forums too.
>
> https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/467336
>
> Also I have found other peoples released Unity Windows Store 8.1 games
>   that suffer from the freezing problem after the ad is displayed
>   sometimes. I guess they didn't notice it. Example: (the first ad
>   popping up froze the game graphics for me):
>
> http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/e...mulator/04eea1ba-8792-437f-a7c2-faec620da6bf#

Following the links seem to show some success with setting it to a Grid:

> Add Width and Height and Background to  and also place it
>   where you want your Ad to appear. If you do not set Width and Height
>   and give your Grid a background color if floods all the screen.

https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/467336

Best answer I can find on this issue, no one seems to have been able to resolve it any other way.